# How to refactor this reducer following separation of concerns and avoiding code duplications?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following React reducer which handles my state for the Profile Module. Although this code work fine, I think I'm doing it wrong because I'm handling the **Loading** states and **Profile** state in the same reducer.

```
function profileReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOADING_START': {
      return { ...state, status: 'pending' }
    }
    case 'LOADING_FAILED': {
      return { ...state, status: 'rejected', error: action.payload }
    }
    case 'LOADING_SUCCESS': {
      return { ...state, status: 'resolved' }
    }
    case 'PROFILES_GET': {
      return { ...state, profiles: action.payload }
    }
    case 'PROFILE_EDIT': {
      return { ...state, profile: action.payload }
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`)
    }
  }
}

function ProfileProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(profileReducer, {
    status: null,
    error: null,
    profiles: [],
    profile: null,
  })
  const value = [state, dispatch];
  return <ProfileContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ProfileContext.Provider>
}
```

The **loading** states are duplicated not only in the **profile** module. It is also used in other modules as well. Is this not code duplication? If so how can I handle this duplication.

PS

I'm using this actions in the following way

```
async function getProfiles(dispatch) {
  dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_START' })
  try {
    const profiles = await client.getProfiles()
    dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_SUCCESS' })
    dispatch({ type: 'PROFILES_GET', payload: profiles })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_FAILED', payload: error })
    throw error;
  }
}

async function addProfile(dispatch, profile) {
  dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_START' })
  try {
    const addedProfile = await client.addProfile(profile)
    const profiles = await client.getProfiles()
    dispatch({ type: 'PROFILES_GET', payload: profiles })
    dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_SUCCESS' })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_FAILED', payload: error })
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I saw a custom hook in usehooks.com/useAsync. Can I use this hook with my current implementation to reuse **Loading** states?

Comment: What you have already looks reasonable. The loading state here refers to a specific piece of data located on the `profiles` property - it would not make much sense anywhere else. Your other loading states presumably correlate to other pieces of data? If you need to await this data specifically then you need a distinct loading state, otherwise you'd just be front-loading all the app's data behind one state flag to reduce "duplication".

Comment: @lawrence-witt yes, my other loading states correlate to other piece of data. I was not thinking to add a global loading state. I was thinking whether I can add another reducer for each piece of data that can be reused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse these specific loading actions between your reducers, you could write a higher-order reducer which augments the more specified ones:

```
function withLoading(reducer) {
  return (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'LOADING_START': {
        return { ...state, status: 'pending' }
      }
      case 'LOADING_FAILED': {
        return { ...state, status: 'rejected', error: action.payload }
      }
      case 'LOADING_SUCCESS': {
        return { ...state, status: 'resolved' }
      }
      default: return reducer(state, action);
    }
  }
}
```

In use:

```
function profileReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PROFILES_GET': {
      return { ...state, profiles: action.payload }
    }
    case 'PROFILE_EDIT': {
      return { ...state, profile: action.payload }
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`)
    }
  }
}

const combinedReducer = withLoading(profileReducer);
```

I think this is the only way that you can usefully reuse code here. Having a generic loading reducer which you create multiples of to access alongside the specific ones just seems like it would add more complexity.

Comment: Hi @lawrence thanks for the answer. other than that is there a way I can further improve my code with this custom hook. https://usehooks.com/useAsync/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the [`useAsync` function that you linked](https://usehooks.com/useAsync/), it would be pretty simple:

```
const getProfilesTask = useAsync(async () => client.getProfiles());

const addProfileTask = useAsync(async (profile) => {
  await client.addProfile(profile);

  // Note, since this is INSIDE the addProfileTask,
  // which is different from running it AFTER
  // the task.
  await getProfilesTask.execute();

}, false);

// If all your tasks will display an error in the same place,
// maybe create a helper function to fetch an error
// from an array of tasks
const error = getProfilesTask.error || addProfileTask.error;

// later
addProfileTask.execute(newProfileHere);
```

Just be aware, for say 5 tasks, you're left with 5 errors and 5 statuses that you need to figure out how you're going to show to the user.

Also, `useAsync` seems to catch errors and do nothing except set status, so in `addProfileTask`, even if `getProfilesTask.execute()` fails, `addProfileTask` will still result in `success`. Up to you if you think that's expected behavior.